# Python 3 - OpenPyXL fill cell does not work

Tags: python-3.6, openpyxl

I'm trying to fill Excel cells with color.
(Ubuntu machine if that matters. Excel file was created with `pandas`)

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('out.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

ws['B5'].fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFEE1111', end_color='FFEE1111', fill_type='solid')
```

After running the script above, I opened `out.xlsx` but nothing changed.

Can someone help please?

Comment: silly question but, are you saving the file after that ?

Comment: Not silly at all apparently... I didn't know that after closing the workbook it's not auto-save it. Thank you!